# how to replace multiple characters in a string?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, replace

how to replace multiple characters in a string?

please help to fix the script

I need to in the line "name" special characters have been replaced by the phrase "special char"

```
newName = replace(name, ['\', '/', ':', '*', '?', '"', '<', '>', '|'], 'special char')
```

but I get the message:

> invalid syntax

Comment: have a look at [str.stranslate()](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=translate#str.translate)

Comment: the invalid syntax error is coming from the first item in your list: '\'.  Since it is an escape character you'd need to use '\\'

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [re.sub()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
import re
newName = re.sub('[\\\\/:*?"<>|]', 'special char', name)
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use [`str.translate`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) and a [dictionary comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
>>> name = ":1?2/3<4|5"
>>> bad = ['\\', '/', ':', '*', '?', '"', '<', '>', '|']
>>> newName = name.translate({ord(c):'special char' for c in bad})
>>> newName
'special char1special char2special char3special char4special char5'
>>>
```

---

If you use [`timeit.timeit`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.timeit), you will see that this method is generally faster than the others supplied:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> name = ":1?2/3<4|5"
>>> bad = ['\\', '/', ':', '*', '?', '"', '<', '>', '|']
>>>
>>> timeit("import re;re.sub('[\\/:*?\"<>|]', 'special char', name)", "from __main__ import name")
11.773986358601462
>>>
>>> timeit("for char in bad: name = name.replace(char, 'special char')", "from __main__ import name, bad")
9.943640323001944
>>>
>>> timeit("name.translate({ord(c):'special char' for c in bad})", "from __main__ import name, bad")
9.48467780122894
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

you could do something like:

```
>>> rep_chars = ['\\', '/', ':', '*', '?', '"', '<', '>', '|']
>>> name = "/:*?\"<>name"
>>> for char in rep_chars:
...     name = name.replace(char,'')
...
>>> name
'name'
```