# Escape characters and raw string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wanto to replase `">"` with `"&gt;"`. And the same for other symbols.

```
def escape_html(s):
    s = s.replace(">", r"&gt;")
    s = s.replace("<", "&lt;")
    s = s.replace('"', "&quot;")
    s = s.replace('&', "&amp;")
    return s

print escape_html(">")
```

The result is `&amp;gt;`

But I need `&gt;`

Could you help me understand why raw string doesn't help me. And how should I write the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace `&` *first*:

```
def escape_html(s):
    s = s.replace('&', "&amp;")
    s = s.replace(">", "&gt;")
    s = s.replace("<", "&lt;")
    s = s.replace('"', "&quot;")
    return s
```

because otherwise you are replacing the `&` in each of the other replacements you made. This has nothing to do with Python raw string literals; that only disables `\`-style escapes.

You could also just use the [`cgi.escape()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html#cgi.escape); set the second argument to `True` to have it escape quotes.

Demo:

```
>>> def escape_html(s):
...     s = s.replace('&', "&amp;")
...     s = s.replace(">", "&gt;")
...     s = s.replace("<", "&lt;")
...     s = s.replace('"', "&quot;")
...     return s
... 
>>> escape_html('<script>alert("Oops & bummer!")</script>')
'&lt;script&gt;alert(&quot;Oops &amp; bummer!&quot;)&lt;/script&gt;'
>>> import cgi
>>> cgi.escape('<script>alert("Oops & bummer!")</script>', True)
'&lt;script&gt;alert(&quot;Oops &amp; bummer!&quot;)&lt;/script&gt;'
```

Comment: @Michael See an old [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28775049/most-efficient-way-to-replace-multiple-characters-in-a-string/28775426#28775426) of mine for more on the matter.