# python how to uppercase some characters in string

Tags: python, string, list, uppercase

Here is what I want to do but doesn't work:

```
mystring = "hello world"
toUpper = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y']
array = list(mystring)

for c in array:
    if c in toUpper:
        c = c.upper()
print(array)
```

`"e"` and `"o"` are not uppercase in my array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`str.translate()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) to have Python replace characters by other characters in one step.

Use the [`string.maketrans()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.maketrans) to map lowercase characters to their uppercase targets:

```
try:
    # Python 2
    from string import maketrans
except ImportError:
    # Python 3 made maketrans a static method
    maketrans = str.maketrans 

vowels = 'aeiouy'
upper_map = maketrans(vowels, vowels.upper())
mystring.translate(upper_map)
```

This is the faster and more 'correct' way to replace certain characters in a string; you can always turn the result of `mystring.translate()` into a list but I strongly suspect you wanted to end up with a string in the first place.

Demo:

```
>>> try:
...     # Python 2
...     from string import maketrans
... except ImportError:
...     # Python 3 made maketrans a static method
...     maketrans = str.maketrans 
... 
>>> vowels = 'aeiouy'
>>> upper_map = maketrans(vowels, vowels.upper())
>>> mystring = "hello world"
>>> mystring.translate(upper_map)
'hEllO wOrld'
```

Comment: @JonClements No wonder AIs are so intelligent today to scrape of codes from puppy's editor

Comment: @JonClements: guess what I [still had open in the other tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29307814/how-to-replace-characters-in-string-by-the-next-one/29307923#29307923). :-P

Answer (score 5):

You are not making changes to the original list. You are making changes only to the loop variable `c`. As a workaround you can try using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate).

```
mystring = "hello world"
toUpper = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y']
array = list(mystring)

for i,c in enumerate(array):
    if c in toUpper:
        array[i] = c.upper()

print(array)
```

Output

```
['h', 'E', 'l', 'l', 'O', ' ', 'w', 'O', 'r', 'l', 'd']
```

Note: If you want `hEllO wOrld` as the answer, you might as well use `join` as in `''.join(array)`

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
mystring = "hello world"
toUpper = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y']

>>> ''.join([c.upper() if c in toUpper else c for c in mystring])
hEllO wOrld
```

Comment: No reason to generate a list.  Omit the brackets and go with a generator expression: `''.join(c.upper() if c in toUpper else c for c in mystring)`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski - Actually, in the case of `str.join`, a list comprehension is generally more efficient.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/2555451.  Of course, with small lists, the difference is pretty negligible.

Comment: @iCodez:  Fair enough.  Stylistically, I still prefer the (nearly imperceptably) simpler code.  Performance can't be our only concern.  We are coding in Python after all.  (Performance-wise, I think that the `maketrans` approach probably wins.)

Answer (score 1):

Use generator expression like so:

```
newstring = ''.join(c.upper() if c in toUpper else c for c in mystring)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that al `c` is not used for anything, this is not passing by reference.

I would do so, for beginners:

```
mystring = "hello world"
toUpper = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y']
array = []
for c in mystring:
    if c in toUpper:
        c = c.upper()
    array.append(c)
print(''.join(array))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job. Keep in mind that strings are immutable, so you'll need to do some variation on building new strings to get this to work.

```
myString = "hello world"
toUpper = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y']
newString = reduce(lambda s, l: s.replace(l, l.upper()), toUpper, myString)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one

```
mystring = "hello world"
toUpper = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y']

array = list(mystring)
new_string = [x.upper() if x in toUpper else x for x in array ]



new_string = ''.join(new_string)
print new_string
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy method

```
name='india is my country and indians are my brothers and sisters'
vowles='a','e','i','o','u'
for name_1 in name:
    if name_1 in vowles:
        b=name_1.upper()
        print(b,end='')
    else:
        print(name_1,end='')
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is code :

```py
    name='india is my country and indians are my brothers and sisters'
    vowles='a','e','i','o','u'
    for name_1 in name:
        if name_1 in vowles:
            b=name_1.upper()
            print(b,end='')
        else:
            print(name_1,end='')
```